# How to set autocite as footfullcite (like "autocite = footfullcite")

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, apa-style, apa6

I would like to show my references with `apa6` style at the bottom of each beamer slide, using `biblatex`.
Currently I set `\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites = true, sorting = nyt, backend = biber, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}` so that `\autocite{}` commands show the citation information at the bottom of a slide. However, `\autocite{}` only produce author-year citation, as shown in the screen-capture below ("1 Allaire et al., 2020").

[image]

I know that `\footfullcite{}` does what I want to get ("2 Xie., Y. (2015)..." in the photo above). Nevertheless, I have used `\autocite{}` so many times previously and in my environment I don't want to replace all `\autocite{}` with `\footfullcite{}`.

So my question is whether there is a way to set `autocite = footfullcite` or whether I can produce `apa6` style citation with `autocite = footnote, style = verbose`. Does anybody have suggestions?

```latex
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  ignorenonframetext,
]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=normal text.fg}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
% Prevent slide breaks in the middle of a paragraph
\widowpenalties 1 10000
\raggedbottom
\setbeamertemplate{part page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\AtBeginPart{
  \frame{\partpage}
}
\AtBeginSection{
  \ifbibliography
  \else
    \frame{\sectionpage}
  \fi
}
\AtBeginSubsection{
  \frame{\subsectionpage}
}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Untitled},
  pdfauthor={Masataka Ogawa},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\newif\ifbibliography
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
% Make caption package work with longtable
\makeatletter
\def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@Manual{R-rmarkdown,
  title = {rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for R},
  author = {JJ Allaire and Yihui Xie and Jonathan McPherson and Javier Luraschi and Kevin Ushey and Aron Atkins and Hadley Wickham and Joe Cheng and Winston Chang and Richard Iannone},
  year = {2020},
  note = {R package version 2.3},
  url = {https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown},
}

@Book{knitr2015,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {https://yihui.org/knitr/},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites = true, sorting = nyt, backend = biber, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\title{Untitled}
\author{CLRR}
\date{2020/10/1}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{R Markdown}
\protect\hypertarget{r-markdown}{}
%\renewcommand{\autocite}[1]{\footfullcite{#1}}

This is an \textcite{R-rmarkdown} presentation \autocite{R-rmarkdown}.

This is knitr\footfullcite{knitr2015}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
  \bibliographytrue
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new `autocite` type with `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand`. But before we can do that we need to define `\footfullcites`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footfullcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footfullcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footfullcite}[f]{\footfullcite}{\footfullcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footfullcite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}

Lorem\autocites[380]{worman}[12]{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Full footnote citations.]

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer! I accepted and up-voted yours!